# Opening a SQLite from bundle using Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have a .sqlite file in my app bundle. I seem to open the file, but I can not access the tables in the file.

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")

//opening the database
 if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
   print("opening database")
    }
 let queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table1"

 var stmt:OpaquePointer?

//preparing the query
 if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
       let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
       print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
       return
     }
```

This gives following error message: "error preparing insert: no such table: Table1"

As I see it, the databse is found and opened, but cannot be accessed. As I see it from other posts at Stackoverflow, this should work

EDIT: I now see that if I misspell the databse name from test.sqlite to ttestt.sqlite, I still get the same error. Meaning the database is not found. What is wrong with this line?

```
 let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")
```

Comment: Does your test.sqlite file already contain the `Table1` table?

Comment: yes, of course. It has to columns, "id" and "color"

Comment: Either the file isn't being found and an empty database is being used (hence no tables) or the sqlite file doesn't really have that table.

Comment: Use `sqlite3_open_v2` and pass `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` to the `flags` parameter. Then you'll know.

Comment: Can you give a code example to that please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870041/swift3-sqlite3-open-open-an-existing-file

Comment: That code solved it. Thank you. The point was that the database has to be copied from the bundle to the documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to copy the database from the bundle to the documnents directory:

```
 let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "sqlite")!
                try manager.copyItem(at: bundleURL, to: documentsURL)
                rc = sqlite3_open_v2(documentsURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil)
```